# Is it possible to add the IBM Connections navigation header into external applications?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I've been looking for a way to inject the IBM Connections header navigation into external applications:

[image]

I feel sure that there's a way to do this with JavaScript, but can't find any documentation to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation would be in the theme customization for oneui which is the basis for the ui in Connections 4.0

http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/index.htm

I'd start with experimenting with a resizable iframe, but that's a guess.